# How to send emails with Django/Celery based on DateTimes stored in the database?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I want to send reminder emails based on different dates saved in the database. I saw some links that was kinda related to that but most of them was really messy.

**Table**
send_email_at: [2022/07/12, 2022/08/19, 2022/07/23, ...]

So the ideal would be to get all **dates > now** and if it's due just send the email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a regular task with beat (as you have tagged in your question) once a day, and in the task, filter your table for the current date, then send emails if anything exists:

```py
@shared_task
def send_emails_if_due():
    if SendEmailAt.objects.filter(when=timezone.now().date()).exists():
        send_emails()
```